# If the phase margin stability test fails at a very high frequency that I will never reach, is this an acceptable design?

Tags: power-electronics, frequency, control-system, stability, phase-margin

If I have a system that fails a phase margin stability test at a very high frequency that I will never reach, can we conclude that my system is stable, given that we will never reach the frequency at which instability is occurring?

Take this figure as an example:

[image]

Here G<sub>vd</sub> is a transfer function for a small-signal buck converter where "vd" stands for duty cycle to output voltage. The dashed line represents the transfer function without any input filters and this is the case of interest.

Notice how at very large frequencies the transfer function will eventually hit the 0 dB point and a 180° phase shift, this is clearly a point of instability by the phase margin test. But at the same time, our system will never operate at this high a frequency. Can we assume that the system is well-designed? Is there any concerns that must be taken into consideration?

Comment: What you show is the control-to-output transfer function of a buck converter. The stability criteria you speak of applies to a compensated loop gain, e.g. your plant transfer function affected by the compensation strategy you purposely select to force an adequate crossover frequency and build phase/gain margins.

Comment: What do you mean with "...that I will never reach"?  When a circuit has a negative stabiliy margin it will be unstable. It does not matter at all if the operating frequency is much lower. In such a case the circuit will develop self-oscillations.

Comment: @LvW
To my understanding this control-to-output transfer function (as Verbal_Kint  mentioned) is a mean to understand how the output would behave in the presence of disturbance at the input (duty-cycle in our case). For example, if we superimposed a ripple to the duty-cycle d with a frequency of  0.9 KHz then we know that this disturbance will be amplified by a factor of 30 dB. Is my understanding flawed?

Comment: @amidher My comment was related only to the question of stability in general, because you have mentioned the phase margin. I did not comment on your Bode diagram which - as it seems - shows the closed-loop behavior (and, hence, cannot be used for finding the phase margin.) Therefore, my comment did not touch the problem as mentioned by Verbal Kint.

Comment: @amidher, you are making assumptions about a power plant whose control-to-output transfer function \$H\$ is represented in the drawing. Once the loop is closed by a compensator \$G\$, you will plot the loop gain \$T(s)=H(s)G(s)\$ and from these information, you can infer how a disturbance will be rejected, most likely by the sensitivity function \$S(s)=\frac{1}{1+T(s)}\$. When the loop gain T is high, the disturbance is vigorously attenuated but as you approach crossover and the gain T weakens, then the disturbance will pass through since the system operates in ac open loop after crossover.

Comment: Thank you all for your replies, its much clearer now.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The system can self-excite just from noise and oscillate, so you want to make sure that at any frequency, not just the intended "operating frequency", the system will be stable.  Usually it does not take a lot more than direct negative feedback through a tiny capacitor that is not relevant at operating frequencies.